# Is the phrase "to [verb]" grammatically correct in this context?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verbs

The following sentence is from this [Physics.SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/731339/a-pendulum-in-a-superfluid):

> Imagine *to submerge* a pendulum in a superfluid.

Shouldn't it be:

> Imagine *submerging* a pendulum in a superfluid.

If I extend the sentence a bit more, it looks like: "I am imagining the *action of submerging* a pendulum in a superfluid" or "I am imagining that *I am going to submerge* a pendulum in a superfluid.". I assume that "to submerge" is coming from the latter sentence but this usage in the condensed sentence looks and sounds odd.

Since the editor didn't correct this, I am assuming that the sentence is correct. In that case, is there is any explanation/example of this usage?

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's based on an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take is that the post contains an error which was not caught. (After quickly skimming some of the editor's answers, I would guess that they're a very competent but non-native speaker.)

Your analysis of the options is correct.